# How to install a cleanup handler for ghci on :quit?

Tags: haskell, process, signals, ghci

When using `:quit`,`:q` or `CTRL+d` in ghci the repl terminates without raising signal as far as I can tell.

How could one execute some cleanup code in this case? I've tried installing several signal handlers to see if that would do the trick, but it doesn't appear as though ghci makes use of these:

```
Prelude> import System.Posix.Signals
Prelude System.Posix.Signals> installHandler sigINT (Catch $ print "cleanup (via INT)") Nothing
Prelude System.Posix.Signals> installHandler sigTERM (Catch $ print "cleanup (via TERM)") Nothing
Prelude System.Posix.Signals> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

The result I was hoping for is `cleanup (..)` being printed to the console to indicate that it was triggered.

I know that it is possible to override `:q` and `:quit` using `:def`, but this doesn't handle my preferred method for exiting the repl, which is `CTRL+d`.

---

The context for this question is this: I've spawned a process to ssh tunnel to a server where an unprotected database is running. This process persists when exiting the repl, which forces me to kill the process manually every time.

```
import qualified System.Process as Process

forkSshTunnel = forkIO $ do
  let sshProc = do
            (_,_,_, phandle) <- Process.createProcess $
                                  (Process.proc "ssh" [ {- ... -} ])
                                  { Process.std_in  = Process.CreatePipe
                                  , Process.std_out = Process.Inherit
                                  , Process.std_err = Process.Inherit
                                  }
            return phandle
  bracket sshProc _terminateSsh _waitForSsh
```

Comment: Sanity check: when I run `ssh my.fun.server ghci` in my shell and hit Ctrl+D, my ssh session ends. Are you saying that ssh does not behave this way for you?

Comment: Also, I understand why you left out the arguments to `ssh`, but you should include your definitions for `_terminateSsh` and `_waitForSsh` to make this a complete question.

Comment: I'm not connecting to ghci via ssh, the ssh tunnel is just a process I spawn to connect to a remote database: `[ "-N", sshUser ++ "@" ++ sshRemoteHost, "-L", localDbPort ++ ":localhost:" ++ sshRemoteDbPort ]`.

Comment: In other words I only provided the second part for context, but I believe the specific process `ssh` should be somewhat irrelevant... (it could as easily be `Process.proc "sleep" [ "999" ]`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the documentation, I believe there is not a good way to do this. You should consider diving into the ghci code yourself to implement this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the help Daniel, I'll see about creating a ticket at least.